# Unity nullable integer as a inspector field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a `Serializable` class for my inspector.

```
[Serializable]
public class CellType
{
    [SerializeField]
    public int? Cost; // This does not appear in the inspector

    [SerializeField]
    public Color MaterialColor;
}
```

The nullable field `Cost` does not appear in the inspector. I use this class by creating a `SerializeField`

```
[SerializeField]
private CellType[] types;
```

If the field `Cost` would be a default int the field would appear. Is a workaround possible?

Comment: This should not have been marked as a duplicate. While it has the words "serializable" and "nullable" in it, the actual intent of the question is entirely different. It's about how to write a property drawer in unity that would render this data type.

Comment: This answer is better than the proposed one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52854129/unity-doesnt-serialize-int-field