# Unity Doesnt Serialize int? field

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, editor, nullable, public

I have a class i want to change the properties of in the editor. So i made my class System.Serializable and made the variables public that i want to be able to change.
 Like so:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UIOptionsRing
{
    public float Radius, DistanceBetweenPoints, StartOffset, GapInDegrees;
    public int? GapAfterElementNumer = 3; //this var doesnt show up
    public Vector3 CircleCenter;
    public GameObject CircleElementsContainer;

}
```

But the problem i am having is that the GapAfterElementNumer is not show up in the editor at all the other fields are. How i can i make it so that `int?` also shows up?

Comment: If this works with just a normal "int" then it is probably because unity doesn't support serialization of "int?"

Comment: I don't think Unity can serialise null fields in the inspector. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nullable types are not serialized in Unity Editor because it's serializer doesn't support `null`. 
There's a small workaround if you're not going to serialize this class to json using `JsonUtility`.
The key idea is that you have to create your own nullable int. Something like

```
public class IntNullable 
{
     public int Value;
     public bool HasValue;
 }
```

Just like it's done inside .NET. Then you can create a [Custom Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) for `IntNullable` or your `UIOptionsRing`. In this editor you can make a filed for int value and a button "Set Null", which will change the value of `HasValue` variable. And further you need to work with this custom `IntNullable` in your code.

Comment: It might be better to assign the highest int value as a place holder for null, and the class has a IsNull() function. It will be more efficient as it will only be 4 bytes as opposed to 5 bytes. (Bools don't actually take up one bit, they take up a byte and sometimes even more).

Comment: @CowNecromancer it depends on your taste. When you use int? in .NET or Unity you still operate with 5 bytes. Using your approach means having some magical number, which you have to keep in mind and 1 byte overhead, I think, isn't significant

Comment: I agree, it's not that much of an issue. But, in some very specific cases the extra byte may not be wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Unity not only can't show nullable fields in the inspector, it cannot serialize them. In order to support this we need to make a custom version of System.Nullable (as @vmchar explains) that is serializable and then give it a property drawer. Making a seamless replacement for System.Nullable is not necessarily obvious, so I've included this example. It should be a drop in replacement for nullable ( `int?` can be replaced with `SN<int>` and all else should work due to the implicit casts) along with a basic custom property drawer.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
  using UnityEditor;
#endif

/// <summary>
/// Serializable Nullable (SN) Does the same as C# System.Nullable, except it's an ordinary
/// serializable struct, allowing unity to serialize it and show it in the inspector.
/// </summary>
[System.Serializable]
public struct SN<T> where T : struct {
  public T Value { get {
    if (!HasValue)
      throw new System.InvalidOperationException("Serializable nullable object must have a value.");
    return v;
  } }

  public bool HasValue { get { return hasValue; } }

  [SerializeField]
  private T v;

  [SerializeField]
  private bool hasValue;

  public SN(bool hasValue, T v) {
    this.v = v;
    this.hasValue = hasValue;
  }

  private SN(T v) {
    this.v = v;
    this.hasValue = true;
  }

  public static implicit operator SN<T>(T value) {
    return new SN<T>(value);
  }

  public static implicit operator SN<T>(System.Nullable<T> value) {
    return value.HasValue ? new SN<T>(value.Value) : new SN<T>();
  }

  public static implicit operator System.Nullable<T>(SN<T> value) {
    return value.HasValue ? (T?)value.Value : null;
  }
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
  [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(SN<>))]
  internal class SNDrawer : PropertyDrawer {

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label) {
      EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

      // Draw label
      position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

      // Don't make child fields be indented
      var indent = EditorGUI.indentLevel;
      EditorGUI.indentLevel = 0;

      // Calculate rects
      var setRect = new Rect(position.x, position.y, 15, position.height);
      var consumed = setRect.width + 5;
      var valueRect = new Rect(position.x + consumed, position.y, position.width - consumed, position.height);

      // Draw fields - pass GUIContent.none to each so they are drawn without labels
      var hasValueProp = property.FindPropertyRelative("hasValue");
      EditorGUI.PropertyField(setRect, hasValueProp, GUIContent.none);
      bool guiEnabled = GUI.enabled;
      GUI.enabled = guiEnabled && hasValueProp.boolValue;
      EditorGUI.PropertyField(valueRect, property.FindPropertyRelative("v"), GUIContent.none);
      GUI.enabled = guiEnabled;

      // Set indent back to what it was
      EditorGUI.indentLevel = indent;

      EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
  }
#endif
```

It's performance may not be on par with System.Nullable, but it should be fine for most purposes. It's been serving me well so far in Unity 2021.1 with C# 4 enabled.

Comment: Note, that property drawer only works for single-line types. Things like `int`, `Color`, `Vector3` should work, but the default property drawer for custom structs will be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on vmchar's answer, which allows null assignment:

```
[Serializable]
public struct NullableInt
{
    public int Value;
    public bool HasValue;

    public NullableInt(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
        HasValue = true;
    }

    public static implicit operator NullableInt(int value) => new NullableInt(value);

    public static implicit operator NullableInt(NullableNull value) => new NullableInt();

    public static implicit operator int(NullableInt value) => value.Value;

    public static implicit operator int? (NullableInt value) => value.HasValue ? value.Value : new int?();
}

public sealed class NullableNull
{
    private NullableNull()
    { }
}
```